# Arquivo de funções comuns entre vários projetos em Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web de grande porte, projeto esse que é um aglomerado de sub-projetos programados em Laravel. Naturalmente, esse projeto possui muitas funções comuns de serem usadas entre diversos arquivos e classes de cada um desses sub-projetos. O que eu gostaria de saber é como criar um arquivo de funções comuns a serem usadas entre todos esses sub-projetos e qual a melhor forma de fazer isso para um projeto com uma grande curva de escalabilidade.

Comment: olha só como está sendo elaborado esse projeto? você poderia explicar dois sub-sistemas? porque dependendo tudo é compartilhado em todos os projetos!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic basicamente terá um projeto intermediário, que receberá as requisições diretamente do usuário. Após recebidas, ele processará essas requisições e fará uma nova requisição a um dos sub-projetos, dependendo do que o usuário requisitou para esse projeto intermediário. Por fim ele vai receber a resposta de um desses sub-projetos e processará essa resposta para o usuário.

Comment: Mas aonde vai estár tudo isso! é um projeto e dentro desse projeto outros projetos?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic São projetos separados, que conversarão entre si através de requisições em cURL, sendo que, por exemplo, desejo  uma função comum para receber e tratar essas requisições.

Comment: Como é Laravel se pode criar pacotes, igual instalamos via https://packagist.org/ e disponibilizar isso para todo o seus outros projetos, pelo menos quando tiver atualizações todos os projetos sofreram alteração ...! essa é a dica que dou!